# How to calculate a GPA by adding up subjects total scores C#

Tags: c#, forms, average, percentage

So for my project (in C#) I need to add up 6 different subjects overall grades and calculate its GPA. I will receive each mark from the subjects  (English /70, math /70, science /50, history /50, geography /50, sport /25) and then I will have to divide them by 6 to find the average. Also I will have to change the average number into a decimal to help find the letter grade. The letter grade ranges from A - F and the % for each grade can be seen below in the pseudo code.

```
BEGIN
        vGPA = (TotalM + TotalE + TotalS + TotalH + TotalG + TotalPE) /6
        
        IF val(vGPA) > 80 THEN
            GPA = 'A & %'
        ELSEIF  val(vGPA) > 65 THEN
            GPA = 'B & %'
        ELSEIF val(vGPA) > 50 THEN
            GPA = 'C & %'
        ELSEIF val(vGPA) > 35 THEN
            GPA = 'D & %'
        ELSEIF val(vGPA) > 20 THEN
            GPA = 'E & %'
        ELSEIF val(vGPA) > 0 THEN
            GPA= 'F & 0%'
        ENDIF   
    END
```

From this I have added all of the different subjects up and then divided by 6 to find the average. Then a letter grade will be given depending on what the overall % is.

Comment: Please include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. We do generally not solve your homework for you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.